# Jquery code requires two individual clicks

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have some issues with JQuery.

Code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#area_results").click(function(){
        $("#areaclickpass2 a").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).html();
            var input = $('#inf_custom_TESTclubarea');
            input.val(value);
            $("#area_results").hide(); // hide results after click
        });
    });
});
```

The current website is requiring 2 clicks to input the value into a field.

I understand why it's doing this (Best solution I can think of to achieve the outcome), however I was curious whether it is possible to achieve the same result by only using a single click.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could create a variable that counts up with each click.  When that `var=2` you do your thing.

Comment: Ehh...your handler requires 2 clicks because your first click binds the handler?

Comment: If the 2 clicks are not necessary, than just remove the outer `$("#area_results").click(function(){` and only bind on the 1 click to the `#areaclickpass2 a` -> `$("#areaclickpass2 a").click(function(){`

Comment: What does your markup look like? You are binding the click function only after you click the `#area_results` element.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that counts up with each click and execute your code when that variable equals 2.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var click_count = 0;
    $("#area_results").click(function(){
         click_count++;
         if(click_count==2){
              var value = $(this).html();
              var input = $('#inf_custom_TESTclubarea');
              input.val(value);
              $("#area_results").hide(); // hide results after click
          }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a event handler within another event handler. `#areaclickpass2` will not be handled unless you click on `#area_results` first.

Just move `$('#areaclickpass2')` event binding out of `#area_results` scope:

```
$("#area_results").click(function(){
     //may not even be necessary to have this
});

$("#areaclickpass2 a").click(function(){
   var value = $(this).html();
   var input = $('#inf_custom_TESTclubarea');
   input.val(value);
   $("#area_results").hide(); // hide results after click
});
```